Excel formatting (RowSpan) messed up
I am exporting a HTML Table using this below.
    var template = `<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/TR/html40/">
<head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>${filename}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/>
</x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml>
<![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head><body>${Table.outerHTML}</body></html>`

Whenever I go down to row 3452 in the Excel file and everything below, the html attribute "rowspan" on the tag "td" no longer works..However, if I open it in chrome as a html file it looks perfect.
If i for example remove a row from where the issue starts, then the row that started with having issues is ok - It is as if once u reach row 3452 then the issues start.
Any idea?
I was expecting the formatting to be correct like before line 3452
This is line/row start 3452
<tr b-0ppczp45qz="">
    <td rowspan="4" b-0ppczp45qz="">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER" target="_blank" b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</a>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="4" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="4" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="4" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="4" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <td rowspan="4" style="background-color: #80FF80" b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" b-0ppczp45qz="">
        <a target="_blank" b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    </td>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" b-0ppczp45qz="">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER" target="_blank" b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</a>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
</tr>
<tr b-0ppczp45qz="">
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: #80FF80;" b-0ppczp45qz="">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER" target="_blank" b-0ppczp45qz="">Passed</a>
    </td>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" b-0ppczp45qz="">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER" target="_blank" b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</a>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
</tr>
<tr b-0ppczp45qz="">
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: #80FF80;" b-0ppczp45qz="">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER" target="_blank" b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</a>
    </td>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" b-0ppczp45qz="">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER" target="_blank" b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</a>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
</tr>
<tr b-0ppczp45qz="">
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: #80FF80;" b-0ppczp45qz="">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER" target="_blank" b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</a>
    </td>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">Approved</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" b-0ppczp45qz="">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER" target="_blank" b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</a>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz=""/>
    <td rowspan="1" style="background-color: " b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <!--!-->
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
    <td b-0ppczp45qz="">PLACEHOLDER</td>
</tr>


Have you actually checked that the output that generates line 3452 is correct?

Hi Rory, yes I have, also opening the XLS in chrome as .html works perfectly fine.

What do the lines either side of line 3452 contain and look like? Excel's HTML output is pretty messed up to begin with so bad behaviour exporting data like this doesn't really surprise me. A screenshot of the transition zone might be helpful.

@MartinBrown I've added in the post the HTML. The reason I am exporting data like that is solely due to the CSS, or else I wouldn't do it like this.

So the exported html markup doesn't correctly reflect the layout of the Excel document after line 3452 then?  Only other thought is try opening it in a smart Wysiwyg HTML editor to see if it can find something that is wrong with the layout.
